# mySQL query - show most popular item

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find the most popular occurrence of an item grouped by date and display the total of all items along with the name of this item. Is something like this possible in a single query?

note: If they are all of equal occurrence (see last 3 rows in Insert) than I can just show at random or the first or last occurrence (whichever is easiest).

If this can't be done in the sql then will have to run through the result and sort the data via PHP which seems like it'll be quite messy.

Edit: Sorry, I had the wrong total for '2009'08-04'. It should be 4.

An example of what I need:

```
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| date       | item                | total |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| 2009-08-02 | Apple               |     5 |
| 2009-08-03 | Pear                |     2 |
| 2009-08-04 | Peach               |     4 |
| 2009-08-05 | Apple               |     1 |
| 2009-08-06 | Apple               |     3 |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Here's an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_popularity` (
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test_popularity` (`date`, `item`, `item_id`) VALUES
('2009-08-02 00:00:00', 'Apple', 1),
('2009-08-02 00:00:00', 'Pear', 3),
('2009-08-02 00:00:00', 'Apple', 1),
('2009-08-02 00:00:00', 'Apple', 1),
('2009-08-02 00:00:00', 'Pear', 0),
('2009-08-03 00:00:00', 'Pear', 3),
('2009-08-03 00:00:00', 'Peach', 2),
('2009-08-04 00:00:00', 'Apple', 1),
('2009-08-04 00:00:00', 'Peach', 2),
('2009-08-04 00:00:00', 'Peach', 2),
('2009-08-04 00:00:00', 'Pear', 3),
('2009-08-05 00:00:00', 'Apple', 1),
('2009-08-06 00:00:00', 'Apple', 1),
('2009-08-06 00:00:00', 'Peach', 2),
('2009-08-06 00:00:00', 'Pear', 3);
```

Comment: This can't really be answered properly without knowing which date should be chosen for each item, or if this really even matters.

Comment: Huh? He wants the most popular for each date. That's how I interpret: "I need to find the most popular occurrence of an item grouped by date"

Comment: I need to group by the date field in which case each row would be a "summary" for that date.

Comment: In your test data you show Pear having an item_id of 0 and of 3. Am I wrong to assume that the item_id has a 1:1 correlation to the item name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My initial suggestion was **incorrect**:

```
SELECT
  date, item, SUM(cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT
    date, item, count(item_id) AS cnt
  FROM test_popularity
  GROUP BY date, item_id
  ORDER BY cnt DESC
) t
GROUP BY date;
```

This erroneously assumes that the outside aggregation (by date) will select the first row of the inner derived table which was ordered by cnt. This behavior is, in fact, undefined and not guaranteed to be consistent.

Here is the proper solution:

```
SELECT
  t1.date, t1.item, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_popularity WHERE date = t1.date) as total
  # see note!
FROM test_popularity t1
JOIN (
  SELECT date, item, item_id, COUNT(item_id) as count
  FROM test_popularity
  GROUP BY date, item_id
) AS t2
ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.item_id = t2.item_id
GROUP BY t1.date;
```

**Note:**

I added the `(SELECT COUNT(*)) AS total` because the question asked for this in one query. However, this will not scale as it is a correlated subquery. This means that for every t1.date the SELECT COUNT(*) subquery will run. Please benchmark and see if it performs suitably for your needs. If not, then I suggest getting the daily totals in a separate query. You would merge these results in your application.

Comment: +1 : simple, nice looking... And you understood the question ^^

Comment: This will give the count of the item but not the total items for that date.

Comment: Thanks hobbodave. I tried to be as clear as possible with the outputted data.
A colleague of mine just pointed out that I need another subselect to count the total for the date. I will post this and answer myself. I'm a n00b on Overflow so please forgive me.

Comment: I didn't get around to running your updated query until just now. It is not producing the correct output. In this case,the entry for '2009-08-04' should show that 'Peach' is the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to hohodave for his initial response:

```
SELECT date, item, cnt, (
SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM test_popularity
WHERE date = t.date
) AS totalCnt
FROM (
SELECT date, item, count( item_id ) AS cnt
FROM test_popularity
GROUP BY date, item_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
)t
GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I could get....

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.date, ItemTotalsByDate.Item, DateTotals.Total
    FROM test_popularity p
    INNER JOIN 
(SELECT date, MAX(cnt) DayMax from
(SELECT date, item, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM dbo.test_popularity
GROUP BY date, item) tbl
GROUP BY date) MaxesByDate
    ON p. date = MaxesByDate.date
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT date, item, COUNT(*) Total FROM dbo.test_popularity
GROUP BY date, item) ItemTotalsByDate
    ON MaxesByDate.date = ItemTotalsByDate.date AND MaxesByDate.DayMax = ItemTotalsByDate.Total
INNER JOIN
(SELECT date, COUNT(*) Total FROM dbo.test_popularity
GROUP BY date) DateTotals
ON p.date = DateTotals.date
```

The only thing this leaves for your PHP  to do is only display the first result it finds for a given date.  I couldn't figure out a good way to arbitrarily pick one item when it was a tie.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Caveat: I did this in SQL Server cuz I didn't have a mySQL instance handy.  I'm pretty sure the subquery syntax I used will work though.

Comment: This does not group by date. It's also needlessly complex with 4 derived tables.