# vb6 ADO query - show most popular item

Tags: vb6, ado

Similar Question I found at [mySQL query - show most popular item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241028/mysql-query-show-most-popular-item) 
but I need little changes, and for VB6 ADO.

I want to create a list of popular (most sold) items, no date range.

An example of table:

```
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| date       | item                |  qty  |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
| 2009-08-02 | Apple               |     5 |
| 2009-08-03 | Pear                |     2 |
| 2009-08-04 | Peach               |     4 |
| 2009-08-05 | Apple               |     1 |
| 2009-08-06 | Apple               |     3 |
+------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Result I need:

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| sl| item   |            | total |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 1 | Apple  |            |     9 |
| 2 | Peach  |            |     4 |
| 3 | Pear   |            |     2 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: What type is your database? The front-end technologie does not matter, in thgis case what is important is the database and the sql dialect it's based on. By using ODBC in VB6 you can retrieve data from any database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have an ADODB.Connection:

```
Dim oRS as New ADODB.Recordset
dim sSql as string

sSql = "SELECT item, SUM(qty) FROM myTable GROUP BY item ORDER BY Item"
oRS.Open sSql, oDBConn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
Do While Not oRS.EOF
     '// Do something with the data'
     oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oRS.Close
```